# Rule of thumb criteria for number of trials needed to do a binomial test

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, sample-size

I have outcomes from a simulation that I expect will exceed a certain number 5% of the time. In order to test if the hypothesis that the probability of an exceedance is indeed 5% I am performing a binomial test, my question is how many trials should I have in order for my test to be meaningful? Obviously I can perform the test for any number of trials and get a test statistic but is there any real of thumb that tells you what an appropriate number of trials is? I assume it would depend heavily on the chosen value of p as wel?

Comment: This have been asked many times, look through https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+sample+size+answers%3A1